# Storing user profiles

Tags: elasticsearch, ldap, identity, openldap, opendj

I would like to store user profile information. After researching a bit online, I am confused between the following options:

1. Use a LDAP server (example: Open DJ) - I can write Java clients which can interact with the LDAP server using LDAP APIs.
2. Store user profile in a database as a JSON document (like in Elastic DB) - The No SQL databases can then index the documents to improve lookup time.

What are the factors that I should keep in mind before selecting one of the approaches?

Answer (score 2):

For a start, if you are storing passwords, then using LDAP is a no brainer IMO. See http://smart421.com/smart-identity-and-fraud/why-bother-with-an-ldap-anyway/ .

Otherwise I would recommend you do a PoC with each solutions (do not forget to add indexes for OpenDJ and you may also use Rest2LDAP) see how they fill your needs. Both products are open source so its easy to get started.

Comment: Good answer. When you think about it, LDAP is a good no-sql choice and typically has built-in access controls.

Answer (score 1):

If your user population is a known group that may already have accounts in an existing LDAP repository, or where user account information needs to be shared between systems, then it makes sense to use and add on to the existing LDAP repository.

If you are starting out from scratch and have mainly external, unknown users who have no other interaction with your infrastructure but this one application, then LDAP is not a good choice imo because of the overhead that you are getting for creating and managing the server. Then a lightweight JSON approach seems better suited (even thought the L in LDAP stands for "lightweight").

The number of expected users is less of a consideration - you need to thread carefully with very large populations in either scenario.

See this questions as well for additional insights [Reasons to store users' data in LDAP instead of RDBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291833/reasons-to-store-users-data-in-ldap-instead-of-rdbms)

Comment: Thanks for the response. As per my understanding, LDAP stores data in a tree structure, whereas a No-SQL database like elastic search would store JSON documents in a flat structure. Are there any specific use cases where i might face issues by not using a LDAP tree structure, if I go with a No-SQL DB? One use case which comes to my mind is when all the users under a particular group need to be moved to another group. Could you please let me know your thoughts on this?

Comment: Most LDAP server use a flat hierarchy for storing just userIDs. Unless it is used also for file and print. (ie Microsoft Active Directory). LDAP is a good choice for no-sql and typically has built-in access controls, password policies etc, etc.

Comment: I don't understand why the tree structure in LDAP is important to you. Unless you want to organize your user population in a hierarchical tree, e.g. with organizational units (OUs), then I don't think the fact that LDAP data is stored in a tree form matters to you because all user objects will be in the same node anyway.